# Laravel include a view with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, laravel, include

I try to include `views` in my page via `javascript` using the following script:

```
<script>$('#b').append(
        <?php 
            echo("@include('include.test_include')");
        ?>
    );</script>
```

But I get an error of `unexpected token`.

I have a view in folder `views/include/test_include.blade.php`

Is there a way to do this :) ?

Comment: Why are you trying to load a blade template with JavaScript? You can just use `@include('include.test_include')` in your template.

Comment: Do not use php tag into append function, You should include directly include view file like `append('@include('include.test_include')')`

Comment: I'm loading a set of dates for month...and i must be able to remove some dates.
So i will load a view with logic for every month ..this views will display dates..and when i remove dates, i only have to reload the selected month view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to the following:

```
<script>
    $('#b').append('@include('include.test_include')');
</script>
```

More documentation on including subviews [in the Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#including-sub-views)

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to do this in your view.

```
<script>
    $('#b').append(‘
        @include('include.test_include')
    ‘);
</script>I
```